# Необязательные параметры функции Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Как сделать, чтоб при указании необязательного параметра при вызове функции другой необязательный параметр тоже надо было указать?

```
def some_func(name, title_id, search_by_id = True, serch_option: str = ''):
    pass
```

Если `search_by_id == False` необходимо будет использовать `search_option`, а `title_id` сделать необязательным параметром.

Comment: Приведите примеры, как вы хотите вызывать функцию в обоих случаях.

Comment: 1 - `some_func('name', 'cost')`
2 - `some_func('name', False, 'class')`
как-то так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def some_func(name, title_id=None, search_by_id=True, serch_option=None):
    if (not search_by_id) and (serch_option is None):
        raise ValueError('Неправильный набор аргументов')
    ...
```